# converting array to vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

what would be the simplest way to convert int array to vector? and use it with if statement.

i.e.

```
int num1[4] = {2, 4, 1, 8};
int num2[4] = {2, 4, 6, 8};

if (testNUM(num1, num2, 4))
  cout << "ERROR: num1 and num2 are reported to be the same.\n";
  else
  cout << "SUCCESS: num1 and num2 are correctly identified "
  << "as different.\n";
```

testNUM is declared as a function prototype (BOOL).

thanks,

Comment: Please define `testNUM`

Comment: `num1` and `num2` are both arrays, why would you need to convert them to vectors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how one converts an array to a vector as part of the vector definition:

```
std::vector<int> v(num1, num1+4);
```

This is how one converts an array to a vector not as part of the vector definition:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.assign(num1, num1+4);
```

Or perhaps you meant "convert my program to use vectors instead of arrays":

```
std::vector<int> num1 = { 2, 4, 1, 8};
```

Comment: 'bool testNUM(int set1[], int set2[], int size);'